# How do I install the evil package?

Tags: evil, package

First time emacs user trying to install "evil mode". I'm attempting to follow the instructions at https://blog.aaronbieber.com/2015/05/24/from-vim-to-emacs-in-fourteen-days.html.

I installed emacs on Ubuntu 18.04 with `sudo apt install emacs`. In `~/.emacs.d/.emacs` I have:

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("org" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa-stable" . "http://stable.melpa.org/packages/"))
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
(package-initialize) 
(require 'evil)
(evil-mode t)
```

After running `M-x package-list-packages` I see `Package refresh done` but neither evil nor evil-mode are in the list and `M-x package-install RET evil` returns `[No match]`

What am I missing?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71877781/getting-a-no-match-when-trying-to-install-evil-from-emacs-m-x-package-install-r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it. The problem was that I had `.emacs` in `~/.emacs.d` rather than in `~/`.

Comment: what does this answer mean? can you clarify? write the full commands you ran and the state of your file please.

Comment: Emacs will either load `~/.emacs` or `~/.emacs.d/init.el`, but not `~/.emacs.d/.emacs` as OP mentioned in the post.  For more information, check out the Emacs Manual on the topic of ["Init File"s](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Evil
Manual installation worked for me: https://evil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html#installation-via-package-el
clone evil repo somewhere you know the path, I recommend ~, so run:

```
    git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil.git
```

then add these line to your `.emacs` file in ~:

```
    vim .emacs
```

add:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "path/to/evil")
(require 'evil)
(evil-mode 1)
```

likely:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/evil")
(require 'evil)
(evil-mode 1)
```

Comment: The question specifically mentions using the package system: providing an answer for a manual installation is at the very least an answer to a different question. Even if one installs manually, a more systematic method than installing in the home directory should be recommended. If everything gets installed in the home directory, it (the home directory) soon becomes a garbage dump.